# How to configure BsonSerializer without use of static registry?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Within a C# project we currently use static methods on BsonSerializer to register serializers for specific types. This happens once on app startup.
However, our acceptance tests start the app up before every test and shut it down after every test, and the second time the app starts up it fails when RegisterSerializer is called, as the registration from the previous test is still in the registry as it's a global static.

Is there any way to register serializers without relying on global statics? Or another strategy for avoiding this problem when running tests?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the MongoDB serializer, you could check if the serializer is already registered before registering it:

```cs
if(BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer<YourCusomType>().GetType() != typeof(YourCusomTypeSerializer))
{
    BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new YourCusomTypeSerializer());
}
```

If you go down this route you should take into account multithreaded scenarios, the above code is not thread safe.

Another option would be to register your own provider and skip the individual serializer registrations:

```cs
public class YourCustomSerializationProvider : IBsonSerializationProvider
{
    public IBsonSerializer GetSerializer(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(YourCusomType)) return new YourCusomTypeSerializer();

        // fall back to Mongo's defaults
        return null;
    }
}

// Where you previously registered individual serializers you will now register your provider instead
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializationProvider(new YourCustomSerializationProvider());
```

This approach would be a bit more IoC friendly and would give you a bit more control.

Comment: The problem with this is that it's either a change to prod code or a significant divergence from prod in the tests

Comment: Jim - can you explain what you mean by prod code? I guess you could try to clear the custom registrations on each test run, but I'm not familiar enough with the MongoDB lib to know if that's possible

Comment: I mean production code, as opposed to test code. Our acceptance tests spin up an instance of our system in process, and the BsonSerializer registration is done within production code, so to add the logic to avoid registering a serializer if one is already registered we have to make a change to that production code. It's not a disaster, but it would be a lot nicer if the BsonSerializer was passed in rather than being a global static. Unfortunately I can't find a way to deregister a serializer either

Comment: Jim - I'm not sure you can avoid making a change to your app's (production) code if you want to avoid multiple registration while running in the same process. If in your tests you can spin up an instance of your system in a separate AppDomain, then you might be able to clear the BsonSerializer registry by unloading the AppDomain on every test cleanup. I think it would be cleaner to make a change to your 'production' app to spin up your own SerializationProvider and manager serializers that way (updated the answer with that option).

Answer (score 1):

Can you register these serializers in static constructor? This way you can call it any number of times you want, the static constructor will not execute more than once.

```
public class BsonSerializerRegisterer
{
    static BsonSerializerRegisterer()
    {
        BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(DateTime), new DateTimeSerializer(DateTimeKind.Utc));
        BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(decimal), new DecimalSerializer(BsonType.Decimal128));
        BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(decimal?), new NullableSerializer<decimal>(new DecimalSerializer(BsonType.Decimal128)));
        BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new EnumSerializer<MyAwesomeEnum>(BsonType.String));
    }

    public static void RegisterSerializers()
    {            
    }
}
```

And then call:

```
BsonSerializerRegisterer.RegisterSerializers()
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice article that can help any future readers

https://www.mydevhub.com/mongodb/adding-custom-type-converter-to-mongodb-in-c/

My solution was to add all `BsonSerializer.*` invokations in the static constructor of `StartUp.cs`